# webView2: inject jQuery in the current page

Tags: winforms, webview2

Starting to play with webView2 in Winforms Net 6.
Is there a way to inject the jQuery library in the current page (which I don't control), so that I can later use jQuery when passing scripts to the page through ExecuteScriptAsync or add event listeners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync`event is what you need. You can find the documentation here: [CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addscripttoexecuteondocumentcreatedasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1054.31#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync_System_String_)

First: Download jQuery and save it to disk.

Next, subscribe to the `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event:

```
private async void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string script = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(@"C:\path\jquery.js");
    await webView21.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);

}
```

Now you will be able to call jquery functions using `await ExecuteScriptAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also injected it when needed as a workaround if `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` just doesn't trigger however you tweak with it.

```
async public Task<string> runJsWithJQ(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webView,string js_file_name,string jq_file_name)
{            
    string no_jq_js = "function f(){return typeof jQuery == 'undefined'} f();";
    var no_jq =await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(no_jq_js);            
    if (bool.Parse(no_jq)) await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(File.ReadAllText(jq_file_name));            
    string result = await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync(File.ReadAllText(js_file_name));
    return result;
}
```