# WebView2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

Tags: javascript, c#, webview2

I'm trying to run a simple JavaScript on page load completed using the [WebView2Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples)

I knocked up a demo page and loaded that  into a WebView2 control and it worked

When I move the script and attempt to load it via C# on a similar webpage I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click') at `<anonymous>:6:17`

[webview2-inject-jquery-in-the-current-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161974/webview2-inject-jquery-in-the-current-page) says to load the JavaScript in the AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsyncevent  which I've done

Hoping someone can suggest what I'm doing wrong

**C#**

```
    private async void WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsSuccess)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"WebView2 creation failed with exception = {e.InitializationException}");
            UpdateTitleWithEvent("CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted failed");
            return;
        }

        this.webView2Control.CoreWebView2.SourceChanged += CoreWebView2_SourceChanged;
        this.webView2Control.CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged += CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged;
        this.webView2Control.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitleChanged += CoreWebView2_DocumentTitleChanged;
        this.webView2Control.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.Image);
        UpdateTitleWithEvent("CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted succeeded");
        string script =  File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Vb\Test\WebView2Samples-main\SampleApps\WebView2WindowsFormsBrowser\Script.js");
        await webView2Control.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Next = document.getElementsByName("next");
if (typeof(Next) != 'undefined' && Next != null)
  {
      // Exists.
      alert(" Found it");
      NextLink[0].click();
  }
else
  {
      alert("Not Found");

   }
```

**Sample HTML**

```
<table >
    <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img name="index" src="../design/images/rsup.png" alt="index"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="image2.html">
        <img  name="next" src="../design/images/rsnext.png" alt="next image"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="image70.html">
        <img name="last" src="../design/images/rslast.png" alt="last image></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Other attempts of performing the click**

```
       document.getElementsByName("next").click();

  document.getElementsByName("next")[0].click();
```

With similar error

Comment: You have `var Next =` then you try to use `NextLink[0]`.  That is of course undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync` adds script that will execute whenever a page is loaded before any other script on the page is run and before the DOM is parsed. So you won't be able to use DOM methods to get the `next` HTML element, because it doesn't exist when your script is run.

In your injected script you could wrap all that in an event listener that waits for the window DOMContentLoaded event:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var Next = document.getElementsByName("next");
  if (typeof(Next) != 'undefined' && Next != null)
    {
        // Exists.
        alert(" Found it");
        NextLink[0].click();
    }
  else
    {
        alert("Not Found");
    }
});
```

Or instead of using `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync`, you could wait for the `CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded` event and then call `ExecuteScriptAsync` to inject your script at that point.

Comment: Your second suggestion makes sense I attempted to add `CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded` to `void AttachControlEventHandlers(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 control)` like this `control.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += WebView2Control_CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;`  I got error `CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  I'm using version 1.0.1248-prerelease